# How to save reference in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm struggling with what seems to be a basic Javascript problem. I generate a unique key for Firebase but that unique key which I want to stay constant keeps changing every time the page refreshes.

```
uniqueKey = function(){
  var key = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;
  return {
    usersKey: key
  };
}();

var addName = function(){
  var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var userNamePath = firebase.database().ref('users/' + uniqueKey.usersKey + '/name');
  userNamePath.set(userName);
  window.location.href="age.html";
}

var addAge10 = function(){
  var userAgePath = firebase.database().ref('users/' + uniqueKey.usersKey + '/age');
  userAgePath.set(10);
  window.location.href="blood_type.html"; 
}
```

[image: image of data tree]

My attempt to solve this issue was to use the revealing module pattern, but I think I'm misunderstanding something. Do I need to separate javascript files..? Please correct me if I'm using bad javascript practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase doesn't support arrays natively, so `push()` is used to create a unique index that can kind-of-sort-of be used to create lists.

Every time `uniqueKey` is initialized, presumably every time you refresh the page, `push()` is called again generating another random index. Assuming the code you posted above is only ran **once** inside of a single javascript context, the two functions `addName` and `addAge10` should write to the same user. My guess is that you're calling the code above multiple times at runtime, generating multiple unique keys.

```
// load script (unique key generated)
addName()
// load script again (different key generated)
addAge10() // set with different key
```

Comment: Is there a way to save this key when the browser refreshes?

Comment: Sure, you can use localStorage or something if you really need to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage